# Recarregar elemento vídeo com link externo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Segue código jQuery:

```
var el = $('#embed_video video').get(0);
var urlVideo = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/matheus/video/upload/ferrari.mp4';
urlVideo = urlVideo + '?t=' + new Date().getTime();
//urlVideo = https://res.cloudinary.com/matheus/video/upload/ferrari.mp4?t=197325475
el.pause();
el.src = urlVideo;
el.load();
el.play();
```

Segue HTML:

```
<div id="embed_video" class="embed-responsive">
    <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls controlsList="nodownload">
        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
        Seu navegador não suporta vídeo em HTML5.
    </video>
</div>
```

Eu uso API da [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/). Eu faço upload de um vídeo no lado servidor com o mesmo URL, porém com vídeo diferente. Com o código acima não está funcionando, estou tentando fazer um "refresh" no elemento vídeo, mas o vídeo antigo permanece o mesmo.

Quando aperto "F5" ou atualiza página, o vídeo funciona como esperava, ele já muda o vídeo carregado na nuvem (cloudinary).

Alguma ideia de como recarregar um vídeo usando jQuery ou Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O navegador guarda em cache o vídeo, portanto não adianta alterar apenas o `src`, é preciso resinserir a tag `video` toda (com o novo `src`). Ficaria assim:

```
var urlVideo = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/matheus/video/upload/ferrari.mp4?'+ new Date().getTime();

var tag_video = '<video class="embed-responsive-item" controls controlsList="nodownload">'
+'<source src="'+ urlVideo +'" type="video/mp4">'
+'Seu navegador não suporta vídeo em HTML5.'
+'</video>';

$('#embed_video').html(tag_video);
$('#embed_video video').get(0).play();
```

Como você está substituindo um HTML por outro, não precisa das funções `.pause()` e `.load()`.